# Unexpected Error on New Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm practicing implementing algorithms in Android, and I keep having issues when trying to debug. The app crashes when I am press the button to pass my array to the new activity to display it and im having a difficult time deciphering the error code. Can anyone tell me what I can do to fix this issue?

**Main Activity**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public final static String SORTING = "com.example.junkyardstar.SORTING";

int [] sortedInt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void insertionSort(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, InsertionSort.class);
    Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
    EditText unsorted = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String unsortedString = unsorted.getText().toString();
    sortedInt = new int[unsortedString.length()];

    for(int i = 0; i < unsortedString.length(); i++)
    {
        sortedInt[i] = Integer.parseInt(unsortedString.substring(i, i+1));
    }

    for(int i = 1; i < sortedInt.length; i++)
    {
        int key = sortedInt[i];

        int temp = i - 1;
        while(i > 0 && sortedInt[temp] > key)
        {
            sortedInt[temp + 1] = sortedInt[temp];
            temp = temp - 1;
        }
        sortedInt[temp + 1] = key;
    }

    mBundle.putSerializable("sorted", sortedInt);
    intent.putExtras(mBundle);
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

**Insertion sort**

```
 public class InsertionSort extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView textView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("sorted");
    int [] sortedList = (int []) bundle.getSerializable("sorted");

    String sortedListString = String.valueOf(sortedList);
    textView.setText(sortedListString);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_insertion_sort, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void onClick()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

**Android Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.junkyardstar.insertionsort" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".InsertionSort"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_insertion_sort" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: What is the content of `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not pass your `int[]` through serializable, `int` is primitive type, so **convert your `int array` into `String array`** and pass, because **`String` extends `Object`** that works with serializable.

Answer (score -1):

```
   mBundle.putIntgerArray("sorted", sortedInt);
    intent.putExtras(mBundle);
    startActivity(intent);


Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras("sorted");
int [] sortedList = (int []) bundle.getIntgerArray("sorted");
try{
   String sortedListString = String.valueOf(sortedList);
}catch(Throwable e){
}
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be mBundle.putIntArray ("sorted", sortedInt)? And I tried but I still have the same issue